# Java GUI app frame doesn't display correctly when launched?

Tags: java, swing

I have made this TicTacToe app using the Java Swing library. Ever since I've added the menu, it wouldn't launch as expected. I mean, the functionality is fine but it would **sometimes** display as one of the three undesirable methods I have in the image when I launch it. However, once I maximize and minimize the frame, it would display in the desired manner.

Kindly help me fix this.

[image]

Comment: just move the `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end of the `setUpFrame()` method :)

Comment: Add `frame.setResizable(false)` if you don't want user to resize it and loose shape

Comment: @Grendan no problem :) i wrote an answer with a little tip, have fun :D

Answer (score 5):

You are adding components to the frame once its already visible. Call `frame.setVisible(true);` only after you have added all components or you will have to revalidate the container. Once a container is visible and layed out, you have to call `validate`/`revalidate` if you add or remove components.

Answer (score 3):

You are showing the frame before all the items are added

```
public void setUpFrame() {
    ...

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just move the `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end of the `setUpFrame()` method :)

i know that i already answer your question but i made this answer because i saw that if i press on the menu item of the exit, it "close" the window, it stays open in the background.

if you want to close the program completly use `System.exit(0);` instead of `frame.setVisible(false);` in the `item_exit ActionListener`

nice game and keep programming ;)